# Weave rows representing email messages into send & reply conversation threads

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have (two) tables of SENT and RECEIVED email messages exchanged between patients and their doctors within an app.  I need to group these rows into conversation threads exactly the way you would expect to see them in your email inbox, but with the following difference:

Here, “thread” encompasses **all** back-and-forth exchanges between the same 2 users.  Thus, each single unique pair of communicating users constitutes 1 and only 1 thread.

The following proof-of-concept code successfully creates a notion of “thread” for a single instance where I know the specific patient and doctor user IDs. The parts I can’t figure out are:

(1) how to accomplish this when I’m pulling multiple patients and doctors from tables, and then

(2) to sort the resulting threads by initiating-date

```
SELECT send.MessageContent, send.SentDatetime, rec.ReadDatetime, other_stuff
FROM MessageSend send
INNER JOIN MessageReceive rec 
ON send.MessageId = rec.MessageId
WHERE
( send.UserIdSender = 123
OR rec.UserIdReceiver = 123 )
AND
(send.UserIdSender = 456
OR rec.UserIdReceiver = 456)
```

Answer (score 0):

If MessageID is unique for a conversion, You can order the messages using the send and received date time.
If you want to filter for particular doctor or patient ,you can include it in the  where clause.

```
SELECT send.MessageContent, send.SentDatetime, rec.ReadDatetime, other_stuff
FROM MessageSend send
  INNER JOIN MessageReceive rec 
     ON send.MessageId = rec.MessageId
ORDER BY   send.MessageId,send.SentDatetime, rec.ReadDatetime
```

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately, because MessageID does not group messages into threads.  It just links a single "sent" to a single "received." The database has no concept of thread. I have to create that in my SQL.

Comment: No takers? Am I asking this question poorly? (I'm a newbie but I learn.)